# Parse IIS7 logs: Anything Google Analytics-like?

Tags: parsing, iis, logging, iis-7, w3c

I am currently using Google Analytics to give me "rich" data on Referrers, clickstreams, etc.  However, looks like I can get as much rich data from IIS 7 (Windows Server 2008) logs (`W3C log` format).

Looking online, I see a ton of tools like `LogParser 2.2`, etc which allow me to parse IIS logs, but then require a ton of custom SQL statements to extract what I need.

**Question**: Is there a tool (*.exe) with GUI or with HTML output that would take as input a log file and output something that looks like Google Analytics report?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an open source project called AWStats that might be useful:

> http://awstats.sourceforge.net/

There's also commercial packages such as SmarterStats that even have a free edition that is restricted to a single site:

> http://www.smartertools.com/smarterstats/web-analytics-seo-software.aspx

Comment: If you want the nitty gritty on actually installin awstats on iis see: http://adventureswith.net/awstats-on-iis7-in-less-steps-than-the-closest-cup-of-coffee-well-almost/

Comment: @FlavorScape: Link doesn't work, seems that was moved to https://adventureswithnet.wordpress.com/2011/03/14/awstats-on-iis7-in-less-steps-than-the-closest-cup-of-coffee-well-almost/