# Analytics in a restricted environment

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, analytics

Does anyone know of an analytics package, either open source or commercial, that can be integrated into a corporate MVC3 site running in a restricted environment?

The (rather rigid) requirements for my project are: -

- The solution must be installed locally, which sadly rules out Google Analytics.
- The solution must track analytics for individual users / customers.
- The solution must work on a Microsoft technology stack and work under IIS 7.5.

Unfortunately due to client sensitivities (I.E., security and brand reputation) they cannot use publically analytics packages and thus rule out [Google](http://www.google.com/analytics), [Open Web Analytics](http://www.openwebanalytics.com/), etc.)

Thanks, and let me know if I need to make the requirements clearer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4496082/parse-iis7-logs-anything-google-analytics-like

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Piwik](http://piwik.org/) is one of the best open source Web Analytics solution. I understand you need a solution in Microsoft stack but this is based on PHP.

I am using this to tracking SharePoint web applications and I am running Piwik using IIS 7.5.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, does Piwik track and report on a specific user / customer, or would the user token have to be passed around via the URL or QueryString?

Comment: I am not sure about that. Please check the online demo or Docs : http://demo.piwik.org/

Answer (score 1):

Configure IIS to use a detailed log. Then use a IIS log analayzer tool (there is plenty, google).

http://awstats.sourceforge.net/ is pretty popular. (PHP, but easy to configure in a separate website in IIS)

A .NET based analyzer: http://www.iis.net/community/default.aspx?tabid=34&i=1864&g=6

Comment: Thanks for the answer, do you know how (or if) the logs can be configured to track for a specific user or customer? I am guessing that using logs you'd have to include some identifier in the URL which was something I was hoping to avoid.